# How do I make a new filtered list out of existing list in Prolog?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm a very newbie to Prolog and I already need help. I looked up other similar questions but it didn't answer my question.

The problem is;
I have a list of mixed elements [Y, rat, gorilla, 30, mother(alex)]. I want to make a new list out of this with exclusively atoms.

So query should look like this.

```
?- atoms([Y, rat, gorilla, 30, mother(alex)], Result).
Result = [rat, gorilla].
```

I tried but I have no idea how to solve this. I think it should be recursive because it needs to check each item weather it's an atom or not.

```
atoms([], []).

atoms([H | T], Result) :-
        atom(H),
        append(H, [], Result).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called "filtering" and there is a ready-made "higher-level predicate" for this already. Why "higher level"? Because it doesn't deal in first-order "objects" only, but takes an executable goal that it calls.

Note that this is an eminently functional approach to programming and there is nothing wrong with that: fat chunks of a "logic program" are actually written in functional style. Here we go:

In SWI-Prolog, the predicate that filters is called [`include/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) or [`exclude/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3).

```
% atoms/2 filters list Li into list Lo using the predicate atom/1
% This only works in direction Li-->Lo.

atoms(Li,Lo) :- include(atom,Li,Lo).
```

And a bit of unit test code:

```
:- begin_tests(filtering).

test("basic test", true(Result = [rat, gorilla])) :-
   atoms([Y, rat, gorilla, 30, mother(alex)], Result).

:- end_tests(filtering).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: filtering . done
% test passed
true.
```

It works.

Of course, you can always write your own `atoms/2` using a recursive call (aka. using an inductive definition)

```
atoms_i([], []).
atoms_i([H|T], [H|Result]) :- % retain the H in the result list
        atom(H),              % the "guard" passes if H is atom
        !,                    % then we commit to this branch
        atoms_i(T, Result).
atoms_i([H|T], Result) :-     % do not retain H in the result list
        \+atom(H),            % the "guard" passes if H is not atom
        !,                    % then we commit to this branch
        atoms_i(T, Result).
```

People will say that you can leave out the `\+atom(H),!` in the third clause for efficieny reasons. Although they are right, I find doing that extremely annoying as I prefer symmetry in the source code and cuts that can in principle be removed at a whim. Plus it's about time the compiler start doing some work to find that efficiency itself. It's 2020, not 1980.

Let's add a bit of unit test code:

```
:- begin_tests(filtering_i).

test("basic test", true(Result = [rat, gorilla])) :-
   atoms_i([Y, rat, gorilla, 30, mother(alex)], Result).

:- end_tests(filtering_i).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: filtering_i . done
% test passed
true.
```

Good.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It was a very clear answer even for a beginner like me. Thank you!

Comment: I agree about preferring explicit tests over cuts. But I disagree with blindly placing cuts. The cut in the third clause of `atoms_i` doesn't do anything: Once you're in the last clause of the predicate, there is no choice anymore to commit to!

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie But why should I think about whether a cut does anything or not?  The cut is a signal to the next guy who comes along and reads the source: that I want to commit to this choice. Leaving it out means the reader has to go to the context: "is this really the last clause?". Prolog should be a dedicated notation for guard parts in any case, as for CHR. If there is a reasonable ground to not add the '!', let's leave it to compiler warnings to raise the issue.

Comment: Leaving it in means the reader has to wonder why the cut is there in the first place. As you can tell by the fact that we are having this discussion. You obviously disagree, and that's fine. Anyway, in this case I would use `( atom(H) -> ... ; ... )` which has all the advantages of having one cut where it matters, not duplicating the guard, and making it explicit that we are are branching on a "semantic" condition (as opposed to the "syntactic" branch due to the different clause heads).

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie That's an interesting idea. Yes, I like that.